# Как указать значение в диапазоне от 50 до 150 при запросе в бд MYSQL LARAVEL?

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm

Использовал различные варианты:

```
->whereRaw("square BETWEEN  ? AND ?", [$from, $to])

->whereRaw("parent_id = ? AND number_floors = ? AND roof = ? AND square > ? AND square < ?",
        [$section, $floor, $roof, $from, $to])

->where([
                ['parent_id', '=', $section],
                ['from', '>', $from],
                ['to', '<', $to],
                ['number_floors', '=', $floor],
                ['roof', '=', $roof],
            ])

 DB::table('projects_store_projects')->where([
                    ['parent_id', '=', $section],
                    ['number_floors', '=', $floor],
                    ['roof', '=', $roof],
                ])->whereBetween('square', [$from, $to])
                    ->offset(0)->limit(2)->get();
```

Ничего не работает, если оставить одно условие, то всё правильно, а два не работают. orWhere не подходит.

Запрос на mysql

```
SELECT * FROM projects_store_projects WHERE square BETWEEN 50 AND 150;
```

Comment: А если доки посмотреть?  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: К тому же запрос который надо получить явно отличается от того, что у тебя в коде

Comment: Запрос, что в самом низу он показывает то, что мне нужно и где ошибка собственно. Метод документации whereBetween не помогает

Comment: "он показывает то, что мне нужно и где ошибка собственно." --- эта фраза совсем не ясна..... " не помогает" --- непонятное объяснение.... не помогает в чём? что он в итоге делает?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос ещё код. Мне нужно получить записи с заданными параметрами parent_id, number_floors, roof и диапазон от 50 до 150 в поле square. Тот код, что я пробовал и указал в вопросе он ничего не возвращает. Если же убрать поле square из запроса, то всё работает.

Comment: А посмотри RAW запрос который в итоге формирует построитель.... и его вбей в любом СУБД . может он тебе ничего и не возвращает потому что и записей нет

Comment: Проблема была в типе данных, я указал для этих переменных тип int и всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
           ->whereBetween('votes', [1, 100])
           ->get();
```

Документация laravel 9x: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses